# Session not storing data

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am using Elliot Haughin's twitter oauth library for codeigniter. It can be found here :
https://github.com/elliothaughin/codeigniter-twitter

I have the following code which authenticates a user with twitter and stores session details.

```
public function login() {




     $this->tweet->set_callback(site_url(''));
     $this->tweet->login();


     $tokens = $this->tweet->get_tokens();
     $user = $this->tweet->call('get', 'account/verify_credentials');
     $u = $user->screen_name ; 



        $data = array(

                'user' => $u,
                'logged_in' => true

        );


        $this->session->set_userdata($data) ; 



}
```

This is weird but the logged_in variable is saved whereas the user is not. I am not sure where i am going wrong.

Comment: What was the output of $user ?

Answer (score 0):

have you include `SESSION` library or autoload it.

Update:
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: yea already did that. If not, logged_in would not have been stored.